# View Renders before Knockout Binds Data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, breeze, single-page-application, durandal

I am sure this has been asked before but alas I can't find it - any help to point me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

I am loading a view / view model with Durandal and during the Activate method I am calling for a single record to be fetched and then displayed.  I am getting the record back (checked the XHR response and all data comes back ok) but I can only assume that the view is loading before the data is ready to display.  No JS errors, no errors at all for that matter, but just a big whitespace in the middle of my screen, even where I know data should show...

ViewModel :

```
define(['durandal/system', 'services/logger', 'services/datacontext'], function (system, logger, datacontext) {
    var aForm = ko.observable();
    var initialized = false;

    function activate(routeData) {
        var id = parseInt(routeData.id);
        return refresh(id);
    };

    function refresh(id) {
        return datacontext.getaFormById(id, aForm);
    }

    var vm = {
        activate: activate,
        aForm: aForm,
        title: "THE TITLE DISPLAYS JUST FINE"
    }
    return vm;
});
```

View :

```
<h3 class="page-title" data-bind="text: title"></h3>

<div class="container-fluid" data-bind="with: aForm">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span12">
            <strong>Testing</strong>
            <strong data-bind="text: id"></strong>        
        </div>
    </div>

    <h2 data-bind="text: description"></h2>
    <h2 data-bind="text: checkType().description"></h2>
</div>
```

I threw in the Testing strong and it doesn't even render, only the title does.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?  I would create a fiddle but it works when I hardcode the data in the ViewModel.

*EDIT :*

Ok after digging into it a bit more it is possible I am not returning the object properly, specifically in the data.entity return type.  Would this cause the issue?

```
    var getaFormById = function (aFormId, aFormObservable) {

        var query = EntityQuery.from('aForms')
            .where('id', '==', aFormId);

        return manager.executeQuery(query)
            .then(querySucceeded)
            .fail(queryFailed);

        function querySucceeded(data) {
            if (aObservable) {
                aObservable(data.entity);
            }
            logger.log('Retrieved selected [aForm] from remote data source', data, system.getModuleId(datacontext), true);
        }
    }
```

Comment: In you viewmodel you have `aForm` but in your html you have `templateForm`.. is it a typo in your question?

Comment: Yes typo that is fixed, thanks.  Changed it for legibility, missed the html.  I am hoping that it is something as stupid as an extra ; but if it is it is alluding me for the past 4 hours.

Comment: It seems you've oversimplified your code to post here. Based on your code I was not able to repro your issue. The view binds fine after the `aForm` has been set asynchronously.

Comment: I am not sure what else would be helpful to post.  Anyone have an idea?  Been plaguing me for a bit now.  If I break the binding the strong 'Testing' shows up but when I fix the binding it goes away again.  Is it possible a callback is not occurring?

Comment: I was able to fix this issue with a work around and returning the aForm differently but I would still like to see the proper way to do this so I am going to leave this question open

Comment: You can try with `if (aObservable) {
                aObservable(data.results[0]);
            }`

Comment: That's actually exactly what I had to do I was just curious if that is the correct solution or a work around

Comment: No this is the correct solution if you check the documentation of `executeQuery` http://www.breezejs.com/sites/all/apidocs/classes/EntityManager.html#method_executeQuery you can see that you need to get the results with `data.results `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not correctly filling your observable in your `executeQuery` success callback that is why your UI is not rendered correctly.

From the `executeQuery` [documenation](http://www.breezejs.com/sites/all/apidocs/classes/EntityManager.html#method_executeQuery) the `successFunction` called with the following argument

> successFunction([data])
>
> - **data** Object
>
>   - **results** Array of Entity
>   - ...

So you need to fill your observable from the `data.results` array and not form `data.entity` (which just returns undefined):

```
if (aObservable) {
   aObservable(data.results[0]);
}
```

Comment: As a note it does not appear to be returning undefined, just not what KnockOut wants to see

Answer (score 0):

You can tell Durandal to hold off binding by returning a jQuery promise() from the activate function.

See this video by Ryan Keeter for the explanation: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w_XjWg6xL8I